# Why not I can execute ".startAnimation" in a "for" loop for several buttons?

Tags: android, coding-efficiency

I have a grid with 12 buttons and I want animate this buttons. I have them in a vector and when I intend execute ".startAnimation" always I have "NullPointer" exception and I don't know why.

I have this:

```
final private int tamGrid=12;


private Button[] botones = new Button[tamGrid];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_juego_grid12);

    loopAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animacionbotongrid12);

    //Asociamos los elementos de la vista:
    asociateElements();       
}

public void asociateElements(){
    String buttonID;
    int resID;

    for(int i=0; i<tamGrid; i++) {
        buttonID="boton"+Integer.toString(i);
        resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id","butterflydevs.brainstudio");
        buttons[i]=(Button)findViewById(resID);
        buttons[i].startAnimation(loopAnimation);
    }

}
```

Why don't work this? The error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in the line of startAnimation.

I've noticed that happens also when i try this:

```
botones[0].setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Acciones del botón:
                        botones[0].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                    }
                }
        );
```

When I use a index in "botones[n]".
It also has this happened to anyone?

Comment: Show how/where you are initializing the `Button`s. Also, you shouldn't use a hard coded length like that, The stacktrace from the crash is always helpful too

Comment: Where is that code at? Is it in a method? Also, what are the button id's in your xml? It isn't being initialized properly.

Comment: code works perfectly when I write the code out of the loop but when I write inside don't work, I dont understand what happen  because of this.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're calling `animateGrid()` before initializing them. You would need to show more code to have a better context and post the **full** stacktrace

Comment: What happens if you put the animation code in the loop that initializes the buttons?

Comment: It does not work either.
     buttons[i]=(Button)findViewById(resID);
     buttons[i].startAnimation(loopAnimation);

Comment: You still need to post the full stacktrace if you want help.

Comment: Are your ids numbered from 0 to 11 or from 1 to 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself, one button was named wrong, and therefore when I through the vector, this cause a Null Pointer Exception.

```
for(int i=0; i<gridSize; i++)
   buttons[i].startAnimation(animation);

for(int i=0; i<gridSize; i++) {
   buttonID="button"+Integer.toString(i);
   resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id","package.name");
   buttons[i]=(Button)findViewById(resID);
}
```

Work with buttons in loops works perfectly. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you put the loop inside `onStart()` callback. Maybe your buttons have not yet been created at that point in your code.